# Set initial AffineTransform on layer, then animate cumulative transform?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation

I've put together a clock animation using QuartzCore on iOS. Each clock hand is a `UIView` Currently, I position the second hand at 12 O Clock & set the anchor point of the second hand view to 0.5, 1.0 so it rotates around its bottom (rather than centre point). Then I add the following animation to the layer:

*(note, this uses a category on CAKeyFrameAnimation to enable a custom easing function, but its outside the scope of the question. For all intents & purposes, the animation behaves just like a regular* `CABasicAnimation`*)*

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *secondHandRotation;
secondHandRotation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"
                                                      function:BounceEaseOut
                                                     fromValue:0
                                                       toValue:(sixDegreesOfRadians)];

secondHandRotation.duration = 1;
secondHandRotation.cumulative = YES;
secondHandRotation.repeatCount = 10000;

[secondHand.layer addAnimation:secondHandRotation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
```

This behaves exactly as expected, however, the second hand always starts at 12 O Clock on the clock face. I would like to start at an arbitrary position. For example, if the current value of "seconds" is 30 seconds, I would like to rotate the secondHand by 180 degrees before I show the clock and start animating it.

I've tried this by adding (before the animation):

```
float initialSecondHandTransform= degreesToRadians(currentTimeComponents.second * 6);
[secondHand setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(initialSecondHandTransform)];
```

But this causes the second hand to jump randomly around the clock face once a second. I've attempted to set the `fromValue` to the `initialMinuteHandTransform` value, and/or tried changing the `toValue` to `initialMinuteHandTransform` + `sixDegreesOfRadians` but I still get erratic movement.

How can I start `secondHand` at an arbitiary position, and animate it by 6 degrees of rotation (a second on the clock face) once per second, indefinitely?

Comment: I am not seeing how you derive your time components... but have you tried logging them? you could also try only running the mod 60 into the degrees to radians method... I don't know why that would matter though.

Comment: The time is just real time from the system clock. So the user might run my app and the time might be 11:30:45 or 11:20:16. The point is the second hand could need to start anywhere, so I need to transform/rotate it to that angle of rotation, then animate. Thats where i'm having trouble. When I apply a transform, THEN try to animate, the "hand" jumps erratically around the clockface. It currently only works properly if the animation starts with no transform applied to the layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `additive` property. It configures the animation to add the animation value to the existing value (a relative animation).

```
secondHandRotation.additive = YES;
```

That way the animation is going to start from the current rotation.

If you would have used a `CABasicAnimation` you could have used the `byValue` property instead of `toValue` and `fromValue`.

Comment: That was it! I was after confusing additive and cumulative. Thank you.